# Array becomes inaccessible during burn API notification chain

Tags: cocoa, swift3

I’m writing an app that burns to optical disks and there’s a strange problem when returning from the burn progress panel.

I call the disk recording setup sheet like this:

```
let setup_panel = DRBurnSetupPanel()
let passed = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self.disk_buckets[current_burn_disk]).toOpaque())
setup_panel.beginSetupSheet(for: self.window, modalDelegate: self, didEnd: #selector(self.burnSetupPanelDidEnd(_:return_code:context_info:)), contextInfo: passed)
```

`disk_buckets` is an array of classes each containing a reference to a `DRTrack` to be burnt - I pass an element so that I can deal with the `DRTrack` reference later.

After the setup panel is dismissed, the following method is then called:

```
func burnSetupPanelDidEnd(_ panel: DRBurnSetupPanel, return_code: Int, context_info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
//…. some code ….
var track:DRTrack = self.disk_buckets[self.current_burn_disk].vDRTrack!
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.progressDidEnd), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: BTVDiscBurnDidEndNotification), object: nil)
self.objc_panel.presentDiscProgressPanel(self.window, burner: panel.burnObject(), layout: track!)
}
```

`objc_panel` is a obj-c singleton that initialises and presents a disc burning progress panel (I did it this way as doing it in Swift is buggy - the progress panel is displayed as a tiny window instead of the default OS one - bug report has been sent to Apple). At the end of the burn `objc_panel` posts the `BTVDiscBurnDidEndNotification` notification to let the `AppDelegate` know it’s finished and so to call:

```
func progressDidEnd(_ note: Notification?) {
        print (“DEBUG count: \(self.disk_buckets.count)")
        print (“DEBUG first element: \(self.disk_buckets[0])")
//…. more code ….
}
```

All goes well until the end of the chain when any attempt to access the first element (or any, for that matter) causes a crash:

```
2016-10-04 14:01:34.654 DiskSpan[4025:220213] *** -[DiskSpan.BackupDisk retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6000cafc0f40
```

(BackupDisk being the class that populates the array)

However, the first line prints out a correct count of the array i.e. 1. So how come I can't access anything in the array during a notification post?

EDIT: I tried `append`ing a dummy item to the array before reading it back and still the crash only occurs when trying to read the array - not write to it.

It should be noted that this worked under Swift 2 and has only become a problem since Swift 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a retention problem. After the call to the obj-c class to start the setup window for burning, the elements in disk_buckets are all over-released. It was a hack but I enumerated over the elements and assigned them to a new array just before calling the setup panel.